# How to make data in var as global using angular2 or typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function, where i get id in console but i am unable to fetch it inside the Apiservice, please can anyone help me to do.

TS:

```
  deleteProduct(index,product) {
    var token = this.auth.getAccessTokenId();
    this.products.splice(index, 1);
    var del = this.products.splice(index, 1);
    del.map(function(product) {
    var Id = product.id;
    console.log(Id);
  })
    this.ApiService
     .deleteProducts(this.Id,token)
     .subscribe(
       products => {
         console.log(products);
         this.products = products;
       }, error => {
         //console.log(error);
       })
  }
```

til  console.log(Id); it works fine, but it is not coming to ApiService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below snippet:

```
 deleteProduct(index) { 
var token = this.auth.getAccessTokenId(); 
var deletedProduct = this.products[index]; 
this.products.splice(index, 1); 
this.ApiService 
.deleteProducts(deletedProduct.id,token) 
.subscribe( 
products => { 
console.log(products); 
this.products = products; 
}, error => { 
//console.log(error); 
}) 
}
```

Comment: EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'Id' of undefined i get this

Comment: At which line you are getting this exception?

Comment: var id = product.id;
    this.Id = product.id;
    console.log(this.Id);

Comment: why you are creating a new id variable in your method?

Comment: From where you are calling 'deleteProduct' method ?

Comment: from html  <button class='btn btn-remove' (click)="deleteProduct(row_ind)">-</button>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160162/discussion-between-ankit-kapoor-and-bhrungarajni).